# Use ng-template with Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I use Angular2 with a JSON script to build a form.

My purpose is to do calculate inputs in the Front-End of my WebApp. I want to see the result of a calcul between 2 inputs.

My calcul is into the string format in my JSON. Can I cast my string to Angular2 calcul ?

```
"Input": {
            "id": "test",
            "type": "text",
            "calc" : "{{2+3}}"
        }
```

And when I write `{{Input.calc}}` I want to see `5` **and not** `{{2+3}}`. Is it possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: I want to create a FormBuilder and add dinamically the calculs in a JSON. Like that, I can build my Forms with a simple JSON !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{}}` (the same as any other Angular2 specific markup) only works when added statically to a template of a component. Everywhere else it's entirely meaningless to Angular2.

Comment: Is it possible to add ngModel with a value contained in a string ?

Answer (score 1):

Expression **`{{}}`** can be used only with the Components in angular. There is no purpose of using it anywhere else.